# How to change the default string into chinese in the form?

Tags: html, forms, character

`LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in my locale,i don't want to change it.

```
<head>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upimage"></br>
<input type="submit" value="上传">
</form>
```

It was displayed as following.
1.How to change the string `Browse...` into `浏览`?
2.How to change the string `No file selected.` into `请选择上传文件`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
   <label for="files"  class="file_class"  name="upimage">浏览</label>
   <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="上传">
```

Then you just style the label

```
 .file_class {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding:5px;
 }
```